# How to export a variable to a fastCGI application in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi

I am using Apache on Linux(RHEL5) and Apache version is 2.2.4. I am running a fastCGI application using Apache and I want to export a variable to this application. I have already tried SetEnv directive in the httpd.conf file but it doesn't seem to work,

Following is in the httpd.conf
SetEnv MALLOC_CHECK_=3

I have also tried to set it using envvars file but still it's not exported in the application.
Following is in the bin/envvars file

export MALLOC_CHECK_=3

I would like to mention that I also have the following in my httpd.conf file

```
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User http
Group http
</IfModule>
```

and I guess that's why it's not being exported in the application i.e Apache is being initially run as root and then changes user to http so basically I have to export this variable to application as an http user. But how?

I start Apache server using:-
./bin/apachectl start (as root)

Is there a way out? I don't want to modify the code of application and use setenv system call to set an environment variable.
Your help would be appreciated. Thanks for your patience.

Regards

gc

Comment: First, check the user name/id that is running apache process. Use "ps -ef | grep apache"

Comment: You mean ps -ef | grep httpd ???

Comment: root      5518     1  0 20:58 ?        00:00:00 /home/http/FCGI_ADSERVER/Install/Apache2/bin/httpd -k start
http      5991  5518  0 21:10 ?        00:00:00 /home/http/FCGI_ADSERVER/Install/Apache2/bin/httpd -k start
http      6456  5518  0 22:02 ?        00:00:00 /home/http/FCGI_ADSERVER/Install/Apache2/bin/httpd -k start

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, I got it

FastCgiServer **-intial-env** *var=value*

Thank you all
:)

Regards

gc